# Need to release resources with Clang using C API?

Tags: c++, memory-management, clang

Sorry for probably silly question: should i release command args vars and unsaved files structures when using Clang C API functions? I do know that in common case one should release resources to avoid memory leaks, but i wonder if Clang does it itself on `clang_disposeTranslationUnit()`.

I'm having clang crash after few iterations of parse/diags + tokenize/dispose so i have to eliminate possible problems one-by-one.

Parsing for example:

```
char **args;
CXUnsavedFile *files;

// allocate args
args = new char*[N];
for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
  int len = strlen(argv[i]);
  args[i] = new char[len + 1];
  args[i][len] = 0;
  strcpy(arg[i], argv[i]);
}

// allocate unsaved files
files = new CXUnsavedFile[M];
for (int i=0; i<M; i++) {
  files[i].Filename = new char[BBB]; // + fill Filename
  files[i].Contents = new char[CCC]; // + fill Contents
  files[i].Length = strlen(files[i].Contents);
}

clang_parseTranslationUnit(..., args, N, files, M);

// release resources (need to do?)

// args
for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
  delete []args[i];
}
delete[] args;

// unsaved files
for (int i=0; i<M; i++) {
  delete []files[i].Filename;
  delete []files[i].Contents;
}
delete []files;
```

UPDATE: for those who think it's really silly question - answer in 30 seconds what is the reason for the crash:

```
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): backtrace:
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): #00  pc 0001832a  /system/lib/libc.so
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): #01  pc 0000dc04  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): #02  pc 0001f0df  /system/lib/libc.so (__assert2+30)
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): #03  pc 0077c954  /data/data/name.antonsmirnov.android.arduinodroid/lib/libclang.so (clang::Lexer::getSourceLocation(char const*, unsigned int) const+76)
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): #04  pc 0077ca4c  /data/data/name.antonsmirnov.android.arduinodroid/lib/libclang.so (clang::Lexer::FormTokenWithChars(clang::Token&, char const*, clang::tok::TokenKind)+100)
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): #05  pc 00781098  /data/data/name.antonsmirnov.android.arduinodroid/lib/libclang.so (clang::Lexer::LexTokenInternal(clang::Token&)+5616)
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): #06  pc 0015de68  /data/data/name.antonsmirnov.android.arduinodroid/lib/libclang.so (clang::Lexer::LexFromRawLexer(clang::Token&)+116)
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): #07  pc 00781d3c  /data/data/name.antonsmirnov.android.arduinodroid/lib/libclang.so (clang::Lexer::getRawToken(clang::SourceLocation, clang::Token&, clang::SourceManager const&, clang::LangOptions const&)+220)
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): #08  pc 00781d9c  /data/data/name.antonsmirnov.android.arduinodroid/lib/libclang.so (clang::Lexer::MeasureTokenLength(clang::SourceLocation, clang::SourceManager const&, clang::LangOptions const&)+36)
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): #09  pc 001d1824  /data/data/name.antonsmirnov.android.arduinodroid/lib/libclang.so (clang::DiagnosticRenderer::emitMacroExpansions(clang::SourceLocation, clang::DiagnosticsEngine::Level, llvm::ArrayRef<clang::CharSourceRange>, llvm::ArrayRef<clang::FixItHint>, clang::SourceManager const&, unsigned int&, unsigned int)+840)
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): #10  pc 001d13ec  /data/data/name.antonsmirnov.android.arduinodroid/lib/libclang.so (clang::DiagnosticRenderer::emitDiagnostic(clang::SourceLocation, clang::DiagnosticsEngine::Level, llvm::StringRef, llvm::ArrayRef<clang::CharSourceRange>, llvm::ArrayRef<clang::FixItHint>, clang::SourceManager const*, llvm::PointerUnion<clang::Diagnostic const*, clang::StoredDiagnostic const*>)+1224)
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): #11  pc 001d1b20  /data/data/name.antonsmirnov.android.arduinodroid/lib/libclang.so (clang::DiagnosticRenderer::emitStoredDiagnostic(clang::StoredDiagnostic&)+304)
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): #12  pc 0017b1c8  /data/data/name.antonsmirnov.android.arduinodroid/lib/libclang.so (clang::cxdiag::lazyCreateDiags(CXTranslationUnitImpl*, bool)+248)
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): #13  pc 00009028  /data/data/name.antonsmirnov.android.arduinodroid/lib/libclang_wrapper.so (Java_name_antonsmirnov_clang_clang_1wrapper_getDiagnostics+72)
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): #14  pc 0001fb70  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): #15  pc 0004e8b9  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+360)
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): #16  pc 00029020  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): #17  pc 0002d7e8  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+180)
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): #18  pc 0005fed5  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+272)
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): #19  pc 0005feff  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): #20  pc 00055327  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): #21  pc 00012e70  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+48)
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): #22  pc 000125c8  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+172)
```

Comment: Whats the problem with `std::vector`?

Comment: i'm not c++ developer so i'd prefer to avoid using std in order to make no errors

Comment: @4ntoine: You're much more likely to make errors, like the one's you made here, if you try to manage memory yourself.

Comment: Don't agree completely. More area to make an error - more possibility to make it. I think i should do things as simple as i can.  So i'm asking you what errors i've made here?

Comment: @4ntoine: I've written an answer with the errors I can spot. But there's *less* area to make an error if you use a ready-made class to manage the memory for you, since you don't need to write the (highly error-prone) deletion code. Having said that, it's good to try this as an educational exercise, to learn why it's best to use properly designed classes in real programs.

Comment: okay, thank you for correction and your point of view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, resources allocated with new have to be released. i had crash because of concurrency issue - concurrent parsing (`clang_parseTranslationUnit`) and indexing (`clang_indexSourceFile()`) of the same file. thanks to Mike.

Answer (score 3):

The most reliable way to manage dynamic memory is to use classes designed for that:

```
std::vector<char const *> args(argv, argv+N);  // replaces first loop

std::vector<CXUnsavedFile> files(M);

// Same loop to set up files
for (int i=0; i<M; i++) {
  files[i].Filename = "test_file.cpp";
  files[i].Contents = "int a = 10;";
  files[i].Length = strlen(files[i].Contents);
}

clang_parseTranslationUnit(..., args.data(), args.size(), files.data(), files.size());

// no need to delete anything.
```

If you really want to manage memory by juggling pointers for educational purposes, then here are the the errors I can spot:

```
args = new char*[N];   // not '*args' - args doesn't point to anything yet

files = new CXUnsavedFile[M]  // not 'new CXUnsavedFile()' - you want an array
```

Don't delete `files[i].Filename` or `files[i].Contents` since you didn't `new` them. They point to string literals, which have static lifetime, meaning they are destroyed automatically at the end of the program.

Comment: yes, that was just mistyping. i had to just copy the source code (the reason i did not is params are actually passed from java using JNI so it should introduce not related information here). corrected. the main question is still the same "*should i release resources myself or clang will do it?*"

Comment: corrected code as it was not close enough to original one (removed const literals). @Mike sorry and thank  you once again

Comment: @4ntoine: The [documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group__CINDEX__TRANSLATION__UNIT.html#ga2baf83f8c3299788234c8bce55e4472e) indicates that Clang doesn't take ownership of the command-line arguments or unsaved files passed to it. You'll need to delete anything you dynamically allocated.

Comment: "The contents and name of these files (as specified by CXUnsavedFile) are copied *when necessary*, so the client only needs to guarantee their validity until the call to this function returns.". What means "when necessary" and does it make an issue for concurrent app? In general i tend to agree that i have to release resources.

Comment: @4ntoine My interpretation is that the files will be **copied** when operation will take place upon them. Regarding the point for concurrent app, yes, it does have an impact. You'll need to verify the validity of the resource Clang will be using. If it is garbage collected before some process try access it, you got a problem. So the issue here would be to keep trace of the resource throughout the concurrent session and make sure it is available when Clang performs the copy, garbage collect only after all Clang copies are finished.

Comment: @4ntoine: "When necessary" means that, if the array contents are going to be needed after the function returns, they will be copied to somewhere managed by Clang. You're free to release them once the function returns (as the documentation says: "the client only needs to guarantee their validity until the call to this function returns").

Comment: @Xephon Agree with you and that's why i copy the string as it's good practice for concurrency to have data copy or synchronize access.

Comment: @Mike, concurrently, there will be a racing condition of garbage collecting the resource and some other process accessing the resource. The point is that the moment of **"function returns"** and the particular **"function"** is not certain in concurrent environment. See my previous comment.

Comment: @4ntonie, glad you're creating copies. But keep in mind, if the resource is big or need to be shared with a big number of processing nodes, maintaining a global copy and assign a distributor might be a better model. Just something for consideration. Happy concurrenting :)